# WPF Menu Popup Placement

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, popup

I have a UI design that I created to mimic the way that apps in Win10 look but in Win7 - 8. I created a Menu that drops down and has several buttons in it. When this drops down it's the height of the app itself. If the app happens to go behind the task bar the menu drop down opens up instead of down. Is there a way to change this behavior so that no matter where the app is located on a screen it will open down even if that means behind the taskbar.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I completely understand where you're coming from and I've been debating that myself. In terms of the behavior I wanted something functional but also something that looked nice. Having the popup go above the application looks bizarre. Plus again I was modeling this off of Win10 apps which don't do that. Thanks again and it's something I'll have to consider.

Comment: Take a look at the Xbox App and then minimize it left to right, basically putting it in a mobile view. It takes the side menu and puts in at the top of the app and drops down when you click it. If you take the app and put it below the taskbar and drop the menu down it stays in the app. Now I know that their menu isn't the same as mine but I was hoping for the same effect.

Comment: We have yet to move to win10 where I work and I've been creating a pretty cool UI api that can be pulled into a WPF project to make all of our apps look and act in a similar manner. So I'm not working with all of the same tools. With the little I have to work with it has actually came out pretty nice. This is a visual bug I would like to fix. I'm thinking about creating my own slide out menu using a stack panel. Thanks again...you've pointed me in the correct direction